How would you build an Async-capable monad transformer stack?
The async library lets us write code like this:
Async.withAsync (getUrl url1) $ \getHandler1 -> do
  Async.withAsync (getUrl url1) $ \getHandler2 -> do
    url1Content <- Async.wait getHandler1
    url2Content <- Async.wait getHandler2
    pure $ url1Content <> url2Content

One limitation of withAsync is that it needs to use IO actions, because its type is withAsync :: IO a -> (Async a -> IO b) -> IO b. It seems I could use the unliftIO package's Async module to use it in a monad transformer that I have with StateT, ExceptT and ReaderT, but I'm unsure if it's possible, or how to do this. Given I'd like to catch my async exceptions into ExceptT in the stack (I think), I'm open to input about best approaches to this. I'd like exceptions to be caught early (and block the rest of the computation from happening); I'd also like the async actions to have full access to the rest of the monad stack. I think that might mean the State would need to potentially be within a TVar (via the STM module), for atomicity, too. Is that correct?
Secondly, is it possible to construct the transformer stack so I don't have to explicitly use withAsync, but rather just make it implicit in the do block of the monad stack any time I add a call to a kind of async function (ie a function like the async function in the async package, but implicitly using withAsync "under the hood"). Ie it would make it so the rest of the monadic action of the do block would naturally ensure the async action is finished. It would hand back a handler that can be wait-ed in the rest of the block.
So, my question is "How would I write a monad transformer stack that works like this?"
Assuming the monad stack is aliased as Context, pseudo-code for using it would look roughly something like this:
main = Context.runContext $ do
  firstPageContentHandler <- Context.getAsync "https://www.google.com"
  secondPageContentHandler <- Context.getAsync "https://www.yahoo.com"
  part1 <- Context.doSync doSomeStuffThatBuildsPartOfAUrl
  part2 <- doSomeMoreStuffThatBuildsPartOfAUrlMaybePurely "with some data"
  let anotherUrl = part1 <> part2
  firstPageContent <- Context.wait firstPageContentHandler
  thirdPageContentHandler <- Context.getAsync (buildUrlFromContent firstPageContent)
  fourthPageContent <- Context.get anotherUrl
  secondPageContent <- Context.wait secondPageContentHandler
  let joinedContent = secondPageContent <> thirdPageContentHandler <> fourthPageContent
  Context.setResponseAs joinedContent
  pure ()



After meditating on this a little more, while this is an interesting intellectual exercise, and I should probably experiment with attempting to program it using unliftIO sometime for fun and interest, what I'm probably actually after in my use case is something like the streaming or streamly libraries, because I don't actually want the concurrency to be unbounded; it should be controlled by the execution context.

After more thought and experiments, I'm tending towards something like newtype ContextMonadT m a = ContextMonadT { runContextMonadT :: Reader.ReaderT (Text, USTM.TVar [Text]) m a } and using MonadUnliftIO and its STM, Async and Exception sub-modules to handle what I need. (USTM is the qualified import name for the STM sub-package). (The Texts are just placeholders for the real types)
